# How to convert Integer to int?

Tags: java, integer

I am working on a web application in which data will be transfer between client & server side.

I already know that JavaScript int != Java int. Because, Java int cannot be null, right. 
Now this is the problem I am facing.

I changed my Java int variables into Integer.

```
public void aouEmployee(Employee employee) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
   Integer tempID = employee.getId();
   String tname = employee.getName();
   Integer tage = employee.getAge();
   String tdept = employee.getDept();
   PreparedStatement pstmt;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/general";
   java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "1234");
   System.out.println("URL: " + url);
   System.out.println("Connection: " + con);
   pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO PERSON SET ID=?, NAME=?, AGE=?, DEPT=?");
   pstmt.setInt(1, tempID);
   pstmt.setString(2, tname);
   pstmt.setInt(3, tage);
   pstmt.setString(4, tdept);
   pstmt.executeUpdate();
 }
```

My problem is here:

```
pstmt.setInt(1, tempID);

pstmt.setInt(3, tage);
```

I cant use the Integer variables here. I tried with `intgerObject.intValue();`
But it makes things more complex. Do we have any other **conversion methods or conversion techniques?**

Any fix would be better.

Comment: I don't understand. You're looking for something simpler than `pstmt.setInt(1, tempID.intValue())`? What's easier than adding 11 characters worth of code?

Comment: Try switching to Java 5 or later: conversion will be done automatically.

Comment: Hey, it works. Thanks. But now problem came here 
"Integer id = rs.getInt(1);".

Comment: @MaRaVan Why is that a problem? It should also work just fine. Have you even tried it?

Comment: Yes, i used .intValue() in setTnt(), and it works. But, Integer id = rs.getInt(1); showing red light now.

Comment: @MaRaVan It sounds like one way or another, your compiler settings are set to something pre-1.5 as Jim Tough said. You should take a look at those, since you shouldn't need to be using `intValue()`.

Comment: Sorry coders, you all were right. Mine JRE 1.4.
I am really sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: *"I already know what JavaScript int != Java int. Because, Java int cannot be null, right."* No, because JavaScript doesn't *have* integers other than temporarily during some operations (e.g., bitwise operators) or as the element type in a typed array like `Int32Array`. A JavaScript number (not int) cannot be `null`. If it's `null`, it's not a number. A *variable* may contain `null`, but if it does, it doesn't contain a number.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As already written elsewhere:

- For Java 1.5 and later you don't need to do (almost) anything, it's done by the compiler.
- For Java 1.4 and before, use `Integer.intValue()` to convert from Integer to int.

BUT as you wrote, an `Integer` can be null, so it's wise to check that before trying to convert to `int` (or risk getting a `NullPointerException`).

```
pstmt.setInt(1, (tempID != null ? tempID : 0));  // Java 1.5 or later
```

or

```
pstmt.setInt(1, (tempID != null ? tempID.intValue() : 0));  // any version, no autoboxing
```

<sup>*</sup> *using a default of zero, could also do nothing, show a warning or ...*

I mostly prefer not using autoboxing (second sample line) so it's clear what I want to do.

Comment: Java 1.4.2 does not have `Integer.valueOf(int)` Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 14):

Since you say you're using Java 5, you can use `setInt` with an `Integer` due to autounboxing: `pstmt.setInt(1, tempID)` should work just fine. In earlier versions of Java, you would have had to call `.intValue()` yourself.

The opposite works as well... assigning an `int` to an `Integer` will automatically cause the `int` to be autoboxed using `Integer.valueOf(int)`.

Comment: How to change this "Integer id = rs.getInt(1);" to integer.

Comment: I did man. It worked for setInt() and i appreciate that. Here, id is Integer & the rs.getInt() returns an int variable. Its not working.

Comment: Sorry coders, you all were right. Mine JRE 1.4.
I am really sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 13):

Java converts Integer to int and back automatically (unless you are still with Java 1.4).

Comment: What happens if an `Integer` is `null`?

Comment: @sparkandshine - a bit late, but well - `null` should cause a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 7):

Another simple way would be:

```
Integer i = new Integer("10");

if (i != null)
    int ip = Integer.parseInt(i.toString());
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you have the compiler settings for your IDE set to Java 1.4 mode even if you are using a Java 5 JDK? Otherwise I agree with the other people who already mentioned autoboxing/unboxing.