# I don't understand how to get my program to return an int value from an integer

Tags: java, integer, int

```
 public static int getComputerMoveAI(int left)
 {
    Integer returnValue = 0;
    Integer place = nimMachine.size() - left;
    returnValue = nimMachine.get(place).get(((int)Math.random()*place)+1);
    plays[place] = returnValue;
    return intValue(returnValue);
 }
```

I want my program to return an int value so that main can work with that but I don't understand how to make that happen. I know it's not correct but I put where I want to change the Integer to an int. I have to use Integer for my arraylist.

Comment: You want `returnValue.intValue()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Integer to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571352/how-to-convert-integer-to-int)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` and `int` will get changed from one to the other automatically as the system needs.  This is known as [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

This can be seen int he following code:

```
class Ideone {
    public static int foo() {
        Integer rv = Integer.valueOf(42);
        return rv;
    }

    public static Integer bar() {
        int rv = 42;
        return rv;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(foo());
        System.out.println(bar());
    }
}
```

([ideone](http://ideone.com/wFWJNV))

This prints out 42 and 42.  But note that the `rv` in `foo()` is an `Integer` and in `bar()` it is an `int` - the 'wrong' type for each return value.

What is going on here is that the `int` is getting converted to an `Integer` in `bar()` and in `foo()`, the `Integer` is getting converted to an `int` for you through the boxing and unboxing process.

You don't need to do an `returnValue.intValue()` or `Integer.valueOf(someInt)` or any other method call to convert one to the other in this case.  Let the system do it for you. It will work.

Comment: Especially because Integer.intValue(someInteger) doesn't exist :)

Comment: @MrZorn thats what I get for doing things this late.  I was mixing the two methods in my head when I really wanted two different method examples.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I started to write out an answer like yours explaining autoboxing but decided to answer the question in the most straightforward way possible due to laziness at this late hour. So kudos to you for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Integer class has an intValue() method on it. Check the javadocs - they are your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29