# Can we change wrapper class into primitive data types?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive, value-of

can we change wrapper to primitive ?if not then what is happening in this code

```
int I = Integer.valueOf(46);
System.out.println(I);
```

I am not getting any error.

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Surely this must have been asked and answered before.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: While I suspect so, at least in the context of other complexities, I'm not sure how I'd find a duplicate in amongst the thousands of other questions relating to unboxing. It's quite nice to have a question which *just* focused on this one detail, rather than it being part of the conditional expression etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Found one, it's quite clean. We can add others if we find them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What about [How to convert Integer to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571352/how-to-convert-integer-to-int)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Right. I prefer this one over that, personally - aside from anything else, in that `Long` version the unboxing is happening well before the assignment; it needs to happen for the operators to work. I'd like this version to not be *deleted*, even if it stays closed as a dupe.

Comment: @JonSkeet: A good dupe can improve the search surface, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called *unboxing*:

```
Integer boxed = 10; // Boxing
int unboxed = boxed; // Unboxing
```

Boxing conversions are described in [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7); unboxing conversions are described in [JLS 5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

Note that if you try to unbox a `null` reference, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown:

```
Integer boxed = null;
int unboxed = boxed; // NPE
```