# Should I convert Integer to int?

Tags: java

I have read threads where the convertion of an Integer to an int is a must, BUT I encountered this thing. My code was :

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String numberOne = "12";

String numberTwo = "45";

Integer myint1 = Integer.valueOf(numberOne);

Integer myint2 = Integer.valueOf(numberTwo);

int sum = myint1.intValue() + myint2.intValue(); //line6

System.out.print(sum);
```

It gave me a warning of unnecessary unboxing at line6 and recommended me this instead:

```
int sum = myint1 + myint2; //newline6
```

Both prints gave me the same result. Isn't it a must to convert Integer to int at line 6?

Comment: read up on auto-unboxing

Comment: It'll unbox for you at some point... You should really be asking why you need to use integer class during psrseInt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler will do the same unboxing automatically for you (since JDK 5), so

```
int sum = myint1.intValue() + myint2.intValue();
```

is a bit redundant and

```
int sum = myint1 + myint2;
```

will have the same behavior.

That said, you can parse the `String`s directly into `int`s, and avoid both the boxing and the unboxing:

```
int myint1 = Integer.parseInt(numberOne);
int myint2 = Integer.parseInt(numberTwo);
int sum = myint1 + myint2;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is unnecessary.

Accoring to [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), `Integer` will be auto unboxed to `int` when you put them besides `+`.

> Numeric contexts apply to the operands of an arithmetic operator.
>
> Numeric contexts allow the use of:
>
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 1.5 or higher you don't need to use Integer.intValue(), it's done by the compiler.
Source: [How to convert Integer to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571352/how-to-convert-integer-to-int)

Comment: It's suggested to add the necessary content from the link into the answer, to make sure it remains relevant even if the link dies